# polyfit does not seem to fit data very well in matlab

Tags: matlab

I am using polyfit in matlab to plot a straight line of best fit through points. However, the best fit line is not as I would expect - the line does not look like it fits the data very well... does it? Here's my code, any help with improving this would be great. (Note, the axis limits I have set are important).

```
x = [0 1 10 5 1 1.5];
y = [-14 -18 -22 -26 -30 -34];
scatter(x,y)
hold on
p = polyfit(x,y,1);
f = polyval(p,x);
plot(x,f,'-r','linewidth',1.2)
ylim([-35 -10])
xlim([-30 30])
```

Comment: What would you expect? It is a regular least square fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your fit looks proper to me, but this might be what you're looking for instead

```
x = [0 1 10 5 1 1.5];
y = [-14 -18 -22 -26 -30 -34];
scatter(x,y)
hold on
p = polyfit(y,x,1);
f = polyval(p,y);
plot(f,y,'-r','linewidth',1.2)
ylim([-35 -10])
xlim([-30 30])
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a total least squares solution

```
data=[x(:), y(:)];
 c=mean(data);
 data=bsxfun(@minus,data,c);

[~,~,v]=svd(data);

d=v(:,end);
k=dot(d,c);

ezplot(@(x,y) x*d(1)+ y*d(2)-k, [-30 30 -35 -10])
```